# how could I capture keyboard input and write it to file?

Tags: c#

I couldn't find any article that would help me. I want to make an application (console, winforms, wpf, really not important) that runs in the background (have it in startup or something) and writes to a file every key that is pressed (in any textbox or stuff like that). For example the computer starts and I open IE and write in the address bar www.bla.com, then open the pokerstars application and write something in the login info or in the textboxes; and at anytime I open the textfile, I find in it what has been written untill then.

can you please suggest a c# approach for this? (I am using windows 7 if that is important)
thanks

Comment: Are you trying to develop a malware?

Comment: I don't know what it seems like or what a keylogger is(if that is something like what I need, then should I look for that keyword on google?)...and I don't know if it is a malware, but I don't think the name is of importance here, but a sollution...so can you help?

Comment: @bokkie yes, you can find programs that do this if you enter 'keylogger' in your favorite search engine. Most uses of applications like this are malicious, for example stealing passwords.

Comment: @CodeCaster and many of the programmers can develop hacks, viruses and stuff like that, right? but they are still not illegal or frowned upon :))... but anyway, not everybody is G-sus Christ :))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you want this for legal&valid purposes..

What you want to create is a keyboard hook. See this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Best regards, and don't be evil..

Comment: I want this for semi-evil purposes.  Prank war at work, and I am writing a program to capture keyboard input and instead output curse words...  hahaha

Answer (score 0):

what you want to write is a key logger.

Search for KeyboardHook and you will find articles like this:

[in c#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) or [in c](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264/KeyBoard-Hooks)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a keylogger. There are many examples on the web how to write one.

You could create a WinForms form and set the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to true, that way you 'intercept' all keypresses, even the one that aren't sent to your application. You could also go native and [use hooks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx).

But usually keylogging is frowned upon. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: catch the ones illegally using my comp :))